# How to call C++ static method

Tags: c++, static-methods

Is it possible to return an object from a static method in C++ like there is in Java? I am doing this:

```
class MyMath {
    public:
       static MyObject calcSomething(void);
    private:
};
```

And I want to do this:

```
int main() { 
    MyObject o = MyMath.calcSomething(); // error happens here
}
```

There are only static methods in the MyMath class, so there's no point in instantiating it. But I get this compile error:

> MyMath.cpp:69: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

What am I doing wrong? Do I *have* to instantiate MyMath? I would rather not, if it is possible.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use `::` instead of `.`

`MyObject o = MyMath::calcSomething();`

When you are calling the method without the object of the class you should use `::` notation. You may also call static method via class objects or pointers to them, in this case you should use usual `.` or `->` notation:

```
MyObject obj;
MyObject* p = new MyObject();

MyObject::calcSomething();
obj.calcSomething();
p->calcSomething();
```

Comment: +1 for noting that you can still call a static function via object-> notation.

Answer (score 12):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are simply using incorrect syntax... the `::` operator ([scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B)) is how you would access classes or members in different namespaces:

```
int main() { 
    MyObject o = MyMath::calcSomething(); // correct syntax
}
```

> Do I have to instantiate MyMath?

No.

Answer (score 2):

Call `MyMath::calcSomething()`

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you want MyMath::calcSomething(). The '.' syntax is for calling functions in objects. The :: syntax is for calling functions in a class or a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyMath {  
public:
    static MyMath* calcSomething(void);
private:
};
MyMath* MyMath::calcSomething()
{
    MyMath *myMathObject=new MyMath;
    return myMathObject;
}
int main()
{   
    MyMath *myMathObject=MyMath::calcSomething();
    /////Object created and returned from static function calcSomeThing   
}
```

Thanks