# Calling static function on class in C++

Tags: java, c++, static-methods

I am writing a lot of java now, so I am getting confused with the java **static** methods and c++ **static** functions.

in java, you can call a static methods from a class, and I frequently use/see it, for exmaple:

```
public class A{
    public void static b(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

You can do, `A.b();` Can you do that in C++? If so, is it not so popular as compared to doing so in java?

Comment: See [Help with C++ static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208853/help-with-c-static-method)

Comment: Stack overflow is not google

Comment: In C++, you would write `A::b();` which does the same thing.

Comment: @Jason before posting a question some effort should be made.

Comment: @Joe agreed. Downvote

Comment: +1 for using correct terminology: java static methods vs. C++ static functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that, in C++ using the `::` scope operator:

```
A::b();
```

And as pointed out, if you are having an instance `a` of your class `A` in the current scope you can also call `a.b()`. Calling a static method on an instance is usually confusing though, so you might want to avoid it.

Comment: If you have an instance `a` of type `A`, you can also use `a.b()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `A::B()`

you can also use `a.B()` if `a` is an instance of `A`. However that is just confusing for someone who reads the code. So just stick to `A::B()` for static methods to clearly show what you meant with it.